# How to get bytes of big file from filepicker

Tags: android, kotlin, file

In the app I use filepicker via which I select file -> convert to bytes -> upload to server:

```
private val filesReceiver =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val data = result.data
                data?.let {
                    val fileUri = data.data!!
                    var name = ""
                    var size: Long? = null

                    fileUri.let { returnUri ->
                        requireContext().contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
                    }?.use { cursor ->
                        val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                        val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                        cursor.moveToFirst()
                        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                        size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
                    }


                    val content = data.data?.let { uri ->
                        requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                            .use { it!!.readBytes() }
                    }
                    val fileContent = String(content!!, Charsets.ISO_8859_1) 
                    if (size != null && size!!.toInt() > 0) {
                        sendingFile(fileContent, name, size!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

it works good with small files (<20mb). But with big files (150+ MB) I receive OutOfMemoryException. I added such in manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

but it did not help me. I thought to use:

```
fun File.readBytes(): ByteArray
```

with building file from the uri, but I got exception about uri format. So, do we have any method to get big files content like I do it with small ones?

### UPDATE

This code is used for sending files in chat. So it can be send via chunks. Here is processing file content:

```
private fun sendingFile(fileContent: String, name: String, size: Long) {
        sendingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
        if (size.toInt() < partSize) {
            sendFilePart(0, fileContent, name, size)
        } else {
            dialog.show()
            for (currentPart in 0..size.toInt().div(partSize)) {
                val slicedString = fileContent.slice(
                    currentPart * partSize
                            until if ((currentPart + 1) * partSize <= fileContent.length) {
                        (currentPart + 1) * partSize
                    } else {
                        fileContent.length
                    }
                )


                if (currentPart in 0..size.toInt().div(partSize)) {
                    dialog.hide()
                    sendingTime = null
                }

                sendFilePart(currentPart, slicedString, name, size)
            }
        }
    }


    private fun sendFilePart(part: Int?, fileContent: String, fileName: String, fileSize: Long) {
        chatVM.mWebSocket.value?.apply {
            if (sendingTime == null) {
                sendingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
            }
            send(
                ChatRequestMessages.sendFilePart(
                    part!!,
                    fileContent,
                    fileName,
                    fileSize,
                    sendingTime!!,
                    chatVM.selectedContact.value?.id!!
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

here chunk size is `private val partSize = 10000`.

Comment: Do not read a complete file in memory. Just open an inputstream for the file and give the uploader the stream. Who was it who asked the same some weeks ago? We have no idea how you upload files but putting files in memory is never needed.

Comment: @blackapps, I'm not sure that it was me, or maybe I asked about some other staff. If you found one of my old questions which you think should help, it will be good when you share here this question link

Comment: Are you using kotlinx-coroutines-core and kotlinx-coroutines-android dependencies in your project.?

Comment: @blackapps, I have updated the question, thank you in advance for you reading and possible help

Comment: @ArnoldBrown, yes, I have them. I also updated the question content, so maybe it will be easier to understand what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I managed to find a solution. Due to the fact that I send the file in chunks, so I did it with such method:

```
fun InputStream.chunkedSequence(chunk: Int): Sequence<ByteArray> {
    val input = this.buffered()
    val buffer = ByteArray(chunk)
    return generateSequence {
        val red = input.read(buffer)
        if (red >= 0) buffer.copyOf(red)
        else {
            input.close()
            null
        }
    }
}
```

and here is processing of file after selection:

```
fun sendFile(context: Context, fileUri: Uri, partSize: Int, callBack: (Any) -> Unit) {
        val sendingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
        var name = ""
        var size: Long? = null

        fileUri.let { returnUri ->
            context.contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
        }?.use { cursor ->
            val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
            size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
        }

        val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(fileUri)

        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                inputStream?.let { inStream ->
                    if (size!!.toInt() < partSize) {
                        sendFilePart(
                            0,
                            String(inStream.readBytes(), Charsets.ISO_8859_1),
                            name,
                            size!!,
                            sendingTime
                        )
                    } else {
                        var part = 0
                        inputStream.chunkedSequence(partSize).forEach {
                            sendFilePart(
                                part,
                                String(it, Charsets.ISO_8859_1),
                                name,
                                size!!,
                                sendingTime
                            )
                            if (part == (size!!.toInt().div(partSize))) {
                                callBack.invoke(true)
                                //inputStream.close()
                            }
                            part += 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

   fun sendFilePart(part: Int?, fileContent: String, fileName: String, fileSize: Long, sendingTime: Long) {
        mWebSocket.value?.apply {
            send(
                ChatRequestMessages.sendFilePart(
                    part!!,
                    fileContent,
                    fileName,
                    fileSize,
                    sendingTime,
                    selectedContact.value?.id!!
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

sometimes it can freeze ui, but in general it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use OkHttp to upload the file you can simply create the request body using Uri to avoid reading the whole file content into the memory:

```
class ContentUriRequestBody(
    private val contentResolver: ContentResolver,
    private val contentUri: Uri
) : RequestBody() {

    override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
        val contentType = contentResolver.getType(contentUri)
        return contentType?.toMediaTypeOrNull()
    }

    override fun writeTo(bufferedSink: BufferedSink) {
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)
            ?: throw IOException("Couldn't open content URI for reading")

        inputStream.source().use { source ->
            bufferedSink.writeAll(source)
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/

Comment: thank you for your message, but no, this file will be send via websocket, so you can check the updated question. Thank you in advance